# What is the number of roots of this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We are given ordered sets of positive integers A and B with n elements each and an integer C, how can we find the number of integer roots of the following equation: 
$\sum_{i=1}^n floor(\frac{A_i*x}{B_i}) = C $ 
I have been stuck on this problem for such a long time. I have tried solving using all the properties of floor functions I know till now, it just doesn't fit into any. 
 An example will be when A = (1,5) and B = (2,4) and C = 3, the number of roots is 1, the root is 5. Any help will be very helpful to me, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE Kindly share your thoughts on the question you put up so as to maximize the number of possible contributors.

Comment: Done :) Thanks for trying to help me out. I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=x_0$ is a solution then so is any x in a small enough interval to the right or the left of $x_0$, so an equation of this form will not have discrete roots - its solution set will consist of one or more intervals (unless it is empty).

If all the rationals $A_i/B_i$ are positive then the sum of the floor functions is a sum of monotonically increasing functions so it is itself a monotonically increasing function of x. Its solution set is therefore either empty or it consists of a single interval. An example with an empty solution set is A=(1,1), B=(1,1), C=1 i.e.
$$2 floor(x) = 1$$

Similar argument holds if all $A_i/B_i$ are negative.

If $A_i/B_i$ are both positive and negative then the solution set can consist of an infinite number of intervals. For example, consider A=(-1,-1,2), B=(1,1,1), C=0 i.e.

$$2floor(-x) +floor(2x)=0$$

Comment: Modified the question, I needed number of integer roots and All A_i and B_i are positive, thank you for your answer :)